# Update org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest to org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest;

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have a function using the deprecated function org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest , and I try to update it with org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest.
The function generate a X509Certificate;

But I have a "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: xmss_SHA256ph" with my new code

The legacy code  :

```
    public X509Certificate generateCertificate(KeyPair keyPair, UserCertificateDTO userCertificateDTO) throws Exception {
        UserDataVOWS newUser = createUserForCertificateRequest(userCertificateDTO);


        X500Principal principal = new X500Principal("CN=" + userCertificateDTO.getEmail());

        PKCS10CertificationRequest pkcs10 = new PKCS10CertificationRequest(
                "SHA256WithRSA",
                principal
                , keyPair.getPublic(),
                null,
                keyPair.getPrivate()
        );

        CertificateResponse certificateResponse = getSOAPClient().certificateRequest(
                newUser,
                new String(Base64.encode(pkcs10.getEncoded())),
                CertificateHelper.CERT_REQ_TYPE_PKCS10,
                null,
                CertificateHelper.RESPONSETYPE_CERTIFICATE
        );

        return certificateResponse.getCertificate();
    }
```

And my update :

```
    public X509Certificate generateCertificate(KeyPair keyPair, UserCertificateDTO userCertificateDTO) throws Exception {
        UserDataVOWS newUser = createUserForCertificateRequest(userCertificateDTO);


        X500Principal principal = new X500Principal("CN=" + userCertificateDTO.getEmail());

        PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder p10Builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
                principal,
                keyPair.getPublic()
        );
        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").build(keyPair.getPrivate());

        PKCS10CertificationRequest pkcs10 = p10Builder.build(signer);


        CertificateResponse certificateResponse = getSOAPClient().certificateRequest(
                newUser,
                new String(Base64.encode(pkcs10.getEncoded())),
                CertificateHelper.CERT_REQ_TYPE_PKCS10,
                null,
                CertificateHelper.RESPONSETYPE_CERTIFICATE
        );

        return certificateResponse.getCertificate();
    }
```

And I Have this error :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: xmss_SHA256ph

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1053)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
    at eu.versusmind.ejbca.controller.CertificateControllerTest.sign(CertificateControllerTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: xmss_SHA256ph
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at eu.versusmind.ejbca.service.EjbcaClientService.generateCertificate(EjbcaClientService.java:204)
    at eu.versusmind.ejbca.service.CertificateService.signConsent(CertificateService.java:71)
    at eu.versusmind.ejbca.controller.CertificateController.sign(CertificateController.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    ... 44 more
```

EjbcaClientService.java:204  => ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").build(keyPair.getPrivate());

Where is my error ?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the same error (albeit in a different environment) by getting rid of the old library reference and adding the newer version.

I took out of my buildpath "bcprov-jdk15on-**160**"

and added "bcprov-jdk15on-**161**"

EDIT:
If you can't take it out, it should work if you restructure the referenced libraries. Both of these projects were able to run in this [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaPZg.png).